How to install sqlsrv for php correctly on local PC?
In general, I followed the instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN and still there is no sqlsrv in phpinfo(). What is in php (File type INI-DEVELOPMENT):
extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_82_ts_x64.dll

My php version: PHP Version 8.2.20 I need this in order to connect to an external database from my local PC (I don’t have a server). But I got an error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\Users\ivakov.av\Desktop\Php_Projects\sigur.php:15 And I need to install sqlsrv correctly, please help!
$serverName = "";
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "",
    "UID" => "", 
    "PWD" => "" 
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}


Are you sure you updated the correct copy of php.ini (phpinfo() will tell you the path of the file). Did you restart the webserver after changing the ini file? Does the file specified in the ini file definitely exist on disk?

In my php folder, which is located on the C:\ drive, there are two files php(ini-development) and php(ini-product). I changed both of these files just in case. And I want to connect to the database using local, my PC, I don't have a server, php runs locally on Windows

Like i said, phpinfo() will tell you which is the correct ini file for the PHP environment you're accessing. Your comment doesn't answer any of my questions, so we haven't moved forward.

I know it's on your computer. That isn't really relevant

Oops, sorry didn't see that.  Loaded Configuration File (none)
How can I connect it?

php(ini-development) and php(ini-product) are both "template" files (with production/development settings). Copy the development file as php.ini in the same folder, make your changes there. As always, the PHP manual has more on the topic

@brombeer, Sorry, I don’t understand a little, do I need to copy the development php.ini file, then just create a php.ini file and then paste the copied text there?

You copy/rename php.ini-development to/as php.ini to the same folder php.ini-development is in. Restart the webserver, phpinfo() should now show you the php.ini file used. Then make changes in that php.ini file

@brombeer Thank you very much, I suffered for ten hours, I don’t even know what else to say, thank you very much

@ADyson Thank you very much, I suffered for ten hours, I don’t even know what else to say, thank you very much
